# Match parent for viewpager inside scrollview not working

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager

I'm trying to put the view pager inside a table row and I set the view pager layout height match parent. the result is that the view pager has no height at all. I have to set the layout height in dp so that the view pager can have a height. But what I'm inflating inside the view pager is dynamic, therefore I can't set the height inside the xml. The scrollview already fill the screen, but the viewpager doesn't have any height at all. Is there any way to get around this? (the view pager that has a problem is the one that has id pager_problem)

EDIT :

okay, now after I change it, the viewpager exists, but only as big as the screen, I want to make the content inside the viewpager scrollable if the fragment content is long (all the layout scrollable, not only the fragment in view pager)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <com.emilsjolander.components.StickyScrollViewItems.StickyScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TableLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <TableRow>
                    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                        android:id="@+id/pager_image"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:layout_height="100dp" />
                </TableRow>
                <TableRow android:tag="sticky">
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:layout_height="50dp"
                        android:id="@+id/tab"
                        android:tag="sticky"
                        android:layout_below="@id/pager_image"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:id="@+id/frame_general_tab"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:gravity="center">
                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:textSize="15dp"
                                android:text="GENERAL"/>
                        </LinearLayout>
                        <LinearLayout
                            android:id="@+id/frame_detail_tab"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:background="@color/gray_F2">
                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:textSize="15dp"
                                android:text="DETAIL"/>
                        </LinearLayout>

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:id="@+id/frame_foto_tab"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:background="@color/gray_F2">
                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:textSize="15dp"
                                android:text="FOTO"/>
                        </LinearLayout>
                    </LinearLayout>
                </TableRow>
                <TableRow>
                    <!--<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/page_container"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="70dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent">
                    </LinearLayout>-->
                    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                        android:id="@+id/pager"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="70dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

                </TableRow>
            </TableLayout>


        </LinearLayout>
    </com.emilsjolander.components.StickyScrollViewItems.StickyScrollView>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <GridLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:columnCount="2"
            android:background="@color/gray_F2"
            android:rowCount="3"
            android:orientation="vertical"

            android:layout_height="70dp">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:textColor="@color/gray_72"
                android:text="Harga mulai"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="25dp"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:text="Rp 10.560.000"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:textColor="@color/gray_72"
                android:text="per kamar per malam"/>

            <Button android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_rowSpan="3"
                android:background="@color/traveloka_button_orange"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:text="LIHAT KAMAR"/>

        </GridLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 17):

You need to set  `android:fillViewport="true"` to the scrollview

```
android:fillViewport="true"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

Comment: use this for scrollview android:layout_height="match_parent"

Comment: already did too, not working. the problem is not on the scrollview, the scroll view appears to fill the screen already. but the viewpager doesn't have any height at all

Comment: okay, now after I change it, the viewpager exists, but only as big as the screen, I want to make the content inside the viewpager scrollable if the fragment content is long (all the layout scrollable, not only the fragment in view pager)

Comment: I had a problem with the scrollview not filling the entire screen, solved it with  android:fillViewport="true"